# Is there any metric $d$ on $\mathbb R$ and $a \in \mathbb R$ such that the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=d(x,a)$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be any metric on $\mathbb R$ , then I know that the two variable scalar field $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ , $g(x,y)=d(x,y)$ is never differentiable . Now what I want to ask is this : Let $a \in \mathbb R$ , then is it true function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=d(x,a) , \forall x\in \mathbb R $ is not differentiable ?

I only know that if $f$ is differentiable  then $f'(a)=0$ and in particular for the standard euclidean metric , $f$ is not differentiable .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $d(x,y) = |x^3 - y^3|.$ Then $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb R$ (which is topologically equivalent to the usual metric on $\mathbb R$). Taking $a=0,$ we have $d(x,0)= |x|^3$ for all $x,$ which is a differentiable function on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: This is included in user254665's [more general answer posted earlier](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1858370/).

Comment: I didn't read that answer because it was rather long, IMO, for the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(u)=u\exp(-1/u^2)$ for $u\not =0$, and $g(0)=0$. We see that $g^{\prime}(0)=0$, and $g^{\prime}(u)>0$ if $u\not =0$. Hence $g$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.Put  $d(x,y)=|g(x-a)-g(y-a)|$; it it easy to se that this is a distance on $\mathbb{R}$. Now $d(x,a)=|g(x-a)|$. As $g$ if differentiable at $u=0$, with $g^{\prime}(0)=0$, we get that $f(x)=d(x,a)$ is differentiable at $a$, (with f^{\prime}(a)=0$).

Let $b>a$. For $x$ close to $b$, we have $x>a$, hence we get $d(x,a)=g(x-a)$ and $d(b,a)=g(b-a)$. Hence $f(x)=d(x,a)$ is differentiable at $b$. Same proof for $b<a$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why do you think your function is differentiable for any real $a$ ?

Comment: And also just to note ... I asked whether $f$ is differentiable ... i.e. differentiable everywhere ....

Comment: @TonyK : What ... ? $f$ is a function of $x$ ...

Comment: @SaunDev: Yes, sorry. But it seems that Matthew's edit answers your comment.

Comment: @TonyK : yes it seems , I am reading it thoroughly now ...

Comment: I'd say that this does not correctly address the question. The OP asks whether for arbitrary $d$ and $a$, the function $x \to d(x,a)$ is differentiable. On the other hand, you show that for arbitrary $a$ there exist a distance $d_a$ such that $x \to d_a (x,a)$ is diferentiable, which is a completely different business.

Comment: @alex M. There exists simple example of $d$ and $a$ such that the function $f(x)=d(x,a)$ is not differentiable at $a$ ($|x-a|$ for example). So I have thinked that the OP question was the question you stated at the end of your comment... But perhaps I am wrong ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $h:R\to R$ be  differentiable and strictly monotonic, with $h(0)=h'(0)=0$ and  with $h' (x)$ continuous at $ x=0. $ (E.g. $h(x)=x^3.$)  For any fixed $a\in R$ let $d(x,y)=|h(x-a)-h(y-a)|.$ It is trivial to verify that $d$ is a metric. Let $f(x)=d(x,a)=|h(x-a)|.$

Any $x<a$ has a nbhd $U$ on which $y\in U\implies f(y)=-h(y-a).$

Any $x>a$ has a nbhd $V$ on which $y\in V\implies f(y)=h(y-a).$

So $f'(x)$ exists for  $x\ne a.$

For any $x\ne a ,$ by the MVT, there exists $x'$  between $x$ and $a$ such that $$f(x)=|h(x-a)|=|h(0)+h'(x'-a)(x-a)|=|h'(x'-a)(x-a)| .$$ So $$\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac {|h(x-a)|-|h(0)|}{x-a}=\frac {|h(x-a)|}{x-a}=\frac {|h'(x'-a)(x-a)|}{(x-a}=\pm h'(x'-a).$$ Now $x'-a\to 0$ as $x\to a,$ and $h'$ is continuous at $0,$ with $h'(0)=0,$ so  we have $f'(a)=0.$